# HTTP Asynchronous programming

Tags: java, http, playframework

Learning how to use the Java PlayFrameWork and it talks about how you can do asynchronous server programming - by that I mean, if a result takes a long time to produce, you can return a promise of a result - informing the browser that a result will be returned.

Can I ask what in HTTP terms this does and how browsers commonly deal with it?

Also, can a result promise be returned to an AJAX call?

Comment: Not sure if it will help but checkout a screencast I did that explains Reactive (Async + Non-Blocking) with Play Framework: http://www.jamesward.com/2013/10/30/intro-to-reactive-composition-with-the-typesafe-reactive-platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is returned to the browser before HTTP response is created by server. This asynchronicity is purely inside Play application and is invisible from client. It's a bit complicated to explain here. This could help you to understand what's going on: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ThreadPools

If you'd like to learn more, take a look at Akka (Play is based on it): http://akka.io/ or I can also recommend perfect course: https://www.coursera.org/course/reactive

To answer your second question, yes of course you can handle AJAX requests asynchronously as well.